# How to implement custom commit interval in runtime on the basis of number of times reader called

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

How to implement custom commit interval which will be decided at runtime on the basis of the number of times the reader called. I am working with spring batch and using FlatfileItemReader to read the record.

Comment: That is what the chunk size does.  Are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think we can't add commit interval at runtime. If you think logically, the job-config file loads (Using context) before initialization of the job. Once job-config file loaded, you can not make any change to the job. If you find the solution of "How to reload job-config at runtime? Or How to load runtime changes of job-config in the context?" then surely you will be able to modify the runtime commit-interval.

Comment: Check if you can modify the object of application context at runtime, if yes then you might get a chance to modify commit-interval.